# Firebase messaging FCM link option of notification push message to foreground PWA does not work

Tags: firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm using onMessage() of Firebase Cloud Messaging JS SDK to receive push messages when my PWA is on foreground, then using these line of codes to show notification to user:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
  });
```

My push message is notification with fcm link option, not data message.
If the push message comes when PWA is on background, the notification is clickable and the fcm link option is open in browser, but when my PWA is on foreground, the notification was show, but when I click on that notification, nothing happens.

How could I make the notification on foregrounded PWA that work with url link in fcm options, I mean when clicking on that link, the target page must be open in browser as if the notification was handled by Firebase SDK when WebApp is on background.

Thanks for any help to solve the issue!